# What is the Convergence Radius and Domain of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}} z^{2^n}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So I need to find the Convergence Radius and Convergence Domain of the complex power series:
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n}} z^{2^n}$

I've tried looking at the individual parts of the series and rewriting it somehow but couldn't find a way.

It can probably be solved, after a step or two, by the formula $R=\frac{1}{\displaystyle\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}$ .

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $a_n=1/n$ if $n$ is a power of $2$ and $a_n=0$ otherwise. Do you see how to use the formula you mention now?

Comment: About the convergence domain, try Dirichlet test to check it's convergent for every $|z|=1$, with $z\neq 1$

Comment: @Wojowu I see, so the partial limits are 0 and 1, the limsup is 1 and the radius is 1, thank you.

Comment: @Jakobian If I found that the radius is 1, doesn't it mean that the series converges inside the unit circle?

Comment: @Roee yes, it means that it converges inside the unit circle. The boundary of the circle, it can converge but doesn't have to

Comment: @Jakobian Dirichlet test is not the right tool to use here, but it's enough to note absolute convergence.

Comment: You havr $i$ for the index of summation and no $i$ in the terms.

Comment: @Wojowu You're right, my mistake. For some reason I treated it like the sum $\sum \frac{1}{n}z^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n \ge 0$, let $a_n = \begin{cases} \frac1n, & n = 2^k\text{ for } k \in \mathbb{N}\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

The radius of convergence $R$ of the power series
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} z^{2^k} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$$
can be computed using the root test.

$$\begin{array}{rll}
\frac1R &= \limsup_{n\to\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}
& \color{blue}{\leftarrow \text{root text}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_{m\ge n} |a_m|^{1/m}
& \color{blue}{\leftarrow \text{definition of "limsup"}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{2^k\ge n}  2^{-\frac{k}{2^k}}
& \color{blue}{\leftarrow \text{only $m$ of the from $2^k$ matter}}\\
&= \lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{k \ge \lceil \log_2n\rceil} 2^{-\frac{k}{2^k}}\\
&= \lim_{\ell\to\infty}\sup_{k \ge \ell}2^{-\frac{k}{2^k}}
& \color{blue}{\leftarrow \text{ $\ell = \lceil \log_2 n \rceil \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$}}\\
&= \limsup_{\ell\to\infty} 2^{-\frac{\ell}{2^\ell}}
& \color{blue}{\leftarrow \text{definition of "limsup" again}}\\
&= \lim_{\ell\to\infty} 2^{-\frac{\ell}{2^\ell}}
& \color{blue}{\leftarrow\text{ limsup = lim whenvever limit exists}} \\
&= 2^{-\lim_{\ell\to\infty} \frac{\ell}{2^\ell}}
& \color{blue}{\leftarrow 2^{-x} \text{ is a continuous function in } x}
\\
&= 2^0 = 1
\end{array}
$$

The radius of convergence of is $1$. The power series converges to some function $f(z)$ analytic over the open unit disk $|z| < 1$.

For any point $z$ on the unit circle, we have

$$\left| \sum_{n\to 0}^\infty a_n z^n \right| \le \sum_{n=0}^\infty |a_n z^n|
= \sum_{n\to 0}^\infty |a_n| = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^k} = 1$$

The power series converges absolutely and hence converges over the unit circle.  This means the power series converges over the whole closed unit disk $|z| \le 1$.

Notice the indices where $a_n \ne 0$ is $n = 2^k$ and $\frac{2^k}{k}$ diverges to $\infty$ as $k \to \infty$. By [Fabry gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry_gap_theorem), the unit circle is a natural boundary for the function $f$.
There is no way to analytic continue $f(z)$ outside the closed unit disk.

This means the domain of the power series is exactly the closed unit disk (even if one
allow analytic continuation).

Comment: A typo, Fabry gap theorem instead of Fabry gay theorem

Comment: @Jakobian oops, what a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Cauchy Condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), which states that the series of the sequence $f(n)$ converges if and only if the series of the sequence $2^n f(2^n)$ converges, the convergence of $a_n=z^{2^n}/2^n$ is equivalent to the convergence of $b_n=z^n/n^2$. Applying the root test and checking the boundary case shows that the series converges whenever $|z|\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

i) If $|z|<1,$ then $|z^{2^n}/2^n| \le 2^{-n}.$ Since $\sum 2^{-n}<\infty,$ the radius of convergence of the series is at least $1.$ ii) If $|z|>1,$ then $|z|^m/m\to \infty$  as $m\to \infty.$ Thus $|z^{2^n}/2^n|\to \infty.$ It follows that the series diverges for such $z,$ which implies the radius of convergence is at most $1.$ Putting i) and ii) together shows the radius of convergence is $1.$